# please insert a disk into usb drive after rufus

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, usb, rufus

I used rufus to install windows on a fresh pc and after the install was finished I booted into windows, removed the usb drive. When I restarted and plugged the usb in it can't detect any media on it  I get "please insert a disk into usb" and 0 bytes showing. I also can't format the drive

[image: DISKPART]

[image: DISKMANAGEMENT]

Comment: [Edit] your question to make it clear what *Disk 2* is exactly,  might also help, if *Disk 0* and *Disk 1* is identified